# What is the difference between a = a.trim() and a.trim()?

Tags: java, string, java-7, jdk1.4

I've ran into a bit of a confusion.

I **know** that `String` objects are *immutable*. This means that if I call a method from the `String` class, like `replace()` then the original contents of the `String` are not altered. Instead, a **new** `String` is returned based on the original. However the *same* variable can be assigned new values.

Based on this theory, I always write `a = a.trim()` where `a` is a `String`. **Everything was fine until** my teacher told me that simply `a.trim()` can also be used. This messed up my theory.

I tested my theory along with my teacher's. I used the following code:

```
String a = "    example   ";
System.out.println(a);
a.trim();      //my teacher's code.
System.out.println(a);
a = "    example   ";
a = a.trim();  //my code.
System.out.println(a);
```

I got the following output:

```
    example   
    example   
example
```

When I pointed it out to my teacher, she said,

> it's because I'm using a newer version of Java (jdk1.7) and `a.trim()`
>   works in the previous versions of Java.

Please tell me who has the correct theory, because I've absolutely **no idea**!

Comment: Maybe she means  `System.out.println(a.trim())`. This will print the trimed string but do not change actual string `a`.

Comment: Drudged up the Java 6 docs; there isn't any difference in `trim()` as far as I can see. Have a look yourself: the [Java 6 doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) and the [Java 7 doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()).

Comment: @ambigram_maker Ask your teacher about the the version she was talking.

Comment: Well, we use jdk1.4 in our school. => obviously no match for jdk1.7! ;)

Comment: ...Sun/Oracle stopped supporting 1.4 over 5 years ago. Not to mention you're missing out on a lot of good things that have been introduced since then.

Comment: Could you ask your teacher to code and compile an example using `a.trim()`? Maybe there's been a misunderstanding such as AJ had suggested.

Comment: As for the application @PakkuDon, she's been using it everywhere... Not just in System.out.println(a.trim());

Comment: `trim()` was as it is from day 1, I believe your teacher made a mistake, or she has done something like `AJ` mentioned.

Comment: Actually, the day that my teacher started to teach us the methods of  class String, she only mentioned "a.trim()". I was the first (and only ) person to raise a question that 'Shouldn't it be "a = a.trim()"?' The reply was "Both are accepted."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

String is immutable in java. And `trim()`  returns a new string so you have to get it back by assigning it.

```
    String a = "    example   ";
    System.out.println(a);
    a.trim();      // String trimmed.
    System.out.println(a);// still old string as it is declared.
    a = "    example   ";
    a = a.trim();  //got the returned string, now a is new String returned ny trim()
    System.out.println(a);// new string
```

**Edit:**

> she said that it's because I'm using a newer version of java (jdk1.7) and a.trim() works in the previous versions of java.

Please find a new java teacher. That's completely a false statement with no evidence.

Comment: Well, that's what I pointed out but my teacher wont't accept it. (plz read last para).

Comment: Funny @Sanjay T. Sharma, that's exactly what we students think! ;)

Comment: Teachers can be wrong. Sometimes it's about subjective things, and you just have to shrug and wonder if they're actually right. In lucky cases like this, the teacher is clearly and objectively wrong. Strings have been immutable [since the beginning](http://web.mit.edu/java_v1.0.2/www/javadoc/java.lang.String.html#_top_).

Comment: @yshavit Reminds me of the time a teacher of mine claimed that Java threw an exception if you overflowed an int. (The guy was teaching C at the time, but he *had* taught Java before)

Comment: Thnx @sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ for supporting that my point of view is correct. Well, I'll make sure that I'll always write "a = a.trim()" as I cannot  find a new teacher. ;)

Comment: Glad to help you :) `A good book also can be a great teacher` :)

Comment: As a matter of fact I follow [Java:The complete reference 8th edition by Herbert Schildt](http://www.herbschildt.com)

Answer (score 3):

Simply using "a.trim()" might trim it in memory (or a smart compiler will toss the expression entirely), but the result isn't stored unless you precede with assigning it to a variable like your "a=a.trim();"

Answer (score 2):

String are immutable and any change to it will create a new string. You need to use the assignment in case you want to update the reference with the string returned from `trim` method. So this should be used:

```
a = a.trim()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to store string value in same or different variable if you want some operation (e.g trim)on string.

```
String a = "    example   ";
System.out.println(a);
a.trim();      //output new String is not stored in any variable
System.out.println(a); //This is not trimmed
a = "    example   ";
a = a.trim();  //output new String is  stored in a variable
System.out.println(a); //As trimmed value stored in same a variable it will print "example"
```

Comment: Don't mind but this answer is similar to that of @sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ. Thnx NE way! :)

Comment: Here best way to explain code is adding comments. I just did that.